# Holo.Dark for Android menu

Tags: android, android-theme, android-menu, android-styles

How can I set theme Holo.Dark only for menu (form menu button)?

I tried this:

```
<style name="menu" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/menu">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        style="@style/menu"/>
</menu>
```

But this doesn't work. How should I do that?

Comment: When you said "for menu button", did you mean for **overflow menu** (list menu) or for the **drawables icons** of your ActionBar?

Comment: I mean menu like this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/U6h38.png

or this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6QFu.png
(without button in red circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set it in your style.xml in general, not with the style attribute in your xml layout:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownList</item>  
</style>

<!-- You can change the parent style as "@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow" -->
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownList" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <!-- background of the list menu -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <!-- dividers -->
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/grey</item>
    <item name="divider">@android:color/grey</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dip</item>
    <!-- item selected -->
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

Read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) for more info, and [this Android Documentation Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html) to get the right color for the background, dividers, text color, etc.
You also can do this dynamically and customize this menu: [Menus My Way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way).
Hope this helps.